# HERE api maps style, How can i delete all objects from map?

Tags: flutter, here-api

Can i erase all layers in https://enterprise.here.com/map-style-editor/?

How can i delete objects like this?
screenshot below from lanzarote island:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0iyc.png

Comment: Hi, would you please confirm which api you use?

Comment: I used navigate sdk 4.7.4.0.1588 version

Answer (score 0):

That would be hard work to customize map style looks like you attached.
We recommend to use "Day Reduced" template in map style editor.
And you'll need to customized the map style based on the template.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkGIx.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhCcU.png

Comment: this is not a solution, I need to understand how to create a separate map style for the flutter

Comment: Yes, you can customize the map style in flutter. There is a guidance and a sample in github.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.8.2.0/dev_guide/topics/custom-map-styles.html#create-and-load-custom-map-styles
 
There is sample code for custom map style.
https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples

Comment: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter thanks for the answer, but where exactly is the example with the styling of the cards?

Comment: Please find CustomMapStyles. There is samples for Android/iOS. here-sdk-examples/examples/latest/explore/android/CustomMapStyles/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what about sample for flutter?

Comment: Please see this guidance https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.8.2.0/dev_guide/topics/custom-map-styles.html#create-and-load-custom-map-styles

Comment: i always have a Map scene not loaded. MapError: MapError.invalidScene, when i used Android/iOS. here-sdk-examples/examples/latest/explore/android/CustomMapStyles/ this sample

Comment: or something like this jss-eng - Referenced definition not found: "Light3.Intensity"; using null. or this - Couldn't find a scene object or scene extension factory registered under the name 'tilezen.line'